# EXTJS 6.5 Row Widget not loading child store

Tags: extjs

I am having trouble using rowwidget plugin. Basically I am trying to load the child using the expandbody event of the parent grid. I can load the parent store and child store as well, but having issues with assigning the child store to the parent store. Please help.

```
//ParentController - called from expandbody listener in the view


onParentExpand: function ( rowNode, record, expandRow, eOpts) {
var childStore = this.getStore('childStore '); // store from viewModel

childStore.load({
    extraParams: {
        param1: record.data.param1,
        param2: record.data.param2
    }
});
```

The above code is throwing this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: store.isLoaded is not a function
at constructor.setStore (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1505247124964:84851)
```

Can someone please help ?

Comment: You have a space at the end: `this.getStore('childStore ')`.

Comment: Good catch, but that was not the issue. The space got in there when i tried to replace with a custom store name :(

Answer (score 0):

After spending hours on this widget, these are my take aways... (I did not take the expandBody approach..)

1. idProperty is mandatory for the Row Widget to work correctly (for models that need explicit Id mapping)
2. My widget wont bind to the dynamic store without the below code

> ```
> onWidgetAttach: function (plugin, bodyComponent, record) {
>   bodyComponent.getStore().load({
>     params: {
>       id: record.get('id'),
>       name: record.get('name'),
>       city: record.get('city'),
>       state: record.get('state')
>     }
>   });
> }
> ```

Also, the widget wont bind to the viewmodel store. I had to create a global store (should research on this)